# Setting up crypto payments via Bitpay

Tags: payment, cryptocurrency, bitpay

I want to set up nodejs bitpay crypto payments. I am trying to test the setup for now.

I have used the bitpay button for it but it doesn't send back the request to the backend at IPN it asks, as my route is: `http://localhost:4000/cryptopay`
[Bitpay Sevice IPN and Browser Redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiSxg.png)

The browser redirect is working but the service IPN is not getting any response from the bitpay. I tried doing `console.log` at the request.

Backend request handler.

```
app.post("/cryptopay", async(req, res) => {
  console.log("Crypto Pay: ")
  console.log(req);
});
```

Even after many successful payments, I don't have any response here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem. First of all Bitpay doesn't support http, you have to go with https. Secondly I don't think they send IPNs to localhosts either. They might require public URLs for them.